# Remove space between buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a calculator in tkinter and I'm trying to get the buttons to be right next to each other like this:

[image: calculator]

This is my code for the buttons so far:

```
Entry(root).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

Button(root, text='C').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
Button(root, text='CE').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')

Button(root, text='0').grid(row=5, column=0)

columncount = 0

for x in range(1, 4):
    Button(root, text=str()).grid(row=4, column=columncount)
    columncount += 1

columncount = 0

for x in range(4, 7):
    Button(root, text=str(x)).grid(row=3, column=columncount)
    columncount += 1

columncount = 0

for x in range(7, 10):
    Button(root, text=str(x)).grid(row=2, column=columncount)
    columncount += 1
```

How do I remove the space?

Comment: You should change `Button(root, text=str()).grid(row=4, column=columncount)` to `Button(root, text=str(x))....` A typo?

Comment: @aristotll Yeah, I forgot the x in that line.Thanks, explained why there were empty buttons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to request that the widgets expand to fill the space given to them. With the `grid` geometry manager you can control that with the `sticky` attribute. You give it a string containing one or more of "n", "s", "e", and "w", representing the points of a compass (north, south, east, west)

For example:

```
Button(root, text=str()).grid(row=4, column=columncount, sticky="nsew")
```

You will need to do that for every button.

If you literally want no space between the buttons, you may also need to turn of the highlight ring which is used to show which button has keyboard focus. This is controlled with the `highlightthickness` attribute, which defaults to 1 pixel.

```
Button(..., highlightthickness=0)
```

It's recommended not to do that, since the ring is important for being able to use the app without a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

set to each button attribut `sticky` to "nsew" - this will let buttons fill whole space given to them it should look something like this:  `Button(root, text=str(x)).grid(row=3, column=columncount, sticky = "nsew")`