# how to reduce space between buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to reduce the spacing between buttons on a *wip* calculator, but when I try to change the height of the Entry field by changing the font size, all the buttons that I have made move further apart, how can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import math

window = Tk()
window.title("Calculator")
window.geometry("250x370")
expression = ""
equation = StringVar()

field = Entry(window,width=35, bd=0,textvariable=equation,font=("Arial 24"))
field.grid(columnspan=4,padx=5,pady=10)
#-------------------------------------------------------


def press(num):
    global expression
    expression=expression+str(num)
    equation.set(expression)

def calculate():
    try:
        global expression
        result= str(eval(expression))
        expression=str(result)
        equation.set(expression)

    except:
        expression=""
        equation.set("error")


def clearer():
    global expression
    expression=""
    equation.set("")


#-------------------------------buttons------------------------------------
button1 = Button(window,text="1",command=lambda:press(1),height=4,width=7)
button1.grid(row=2,column=0)

button2 = Button(window,text="2",command=lambda:press(2),height=4,width=7)
button2.grid(row=2,column=1)

button3 = Button(window,text="3",command=lambda:press(3),height=4,width=7)
button3.grid(row=2,column=2)

button4 = Button(window,text="4",command=lambda:press(4),height=4,width=7)
button4.grid(row=3,column=0)

button5 = Button(window,text="5",command=lambda:press(5),height=4,width=7,)
button5.grid(row=3,column=1)

button6 = Button(window,text="6",command=lambda:press(6),height=4,width=7)
button6.grid(row=3,column=2)

button7 = Button(window,text="7",command=lambda:press(7),height=4,width=7)
button7.grid(row=4,column=0)

button8 = Button(window,text="8",command=lambda:press(8),height=4,width=7)
button8.grid(row=4,column=1)

button9 = Button(window,text="9",command=lambda:press(9),height=4,width=7)
button9.grid(row=4,column=2)

button0 = Button(window,text="0",command=lambda:press(0),height=4,width=7)
button0.grid(row=5,column=0)

clear = Button(window,text="Clear",command=clearer,height=4,width=7)
clear.grid(row=5,column=1)

equals = Button(window,text="=",command=calculate,height=4,width=7)
equals.grid(row=5,column=2)

plus = Button(window,text="+",command=lambda:press("+"),height=4,width=7)
plus.grid(row=2,column=3)

minus = Button(window,text="-",command=lambda:press("-"),height=4,width=7)
minus.grid(row=3,column=3)

multiply = Button(window,text="*",command=lambda:press("*"),height=4,width=7)
multiply.grid(row=4,column=3)

divide = Button(window,text="/",command=lambda:press("/"),height=4,width=7)
divide.grid(row=5,column=3)

window.mainloop()
```

`field = Entry(window,width=35, bd=0,textvariable=equation,font=("Arial 24"))` | the `-font=("Arial 24)` is what is causing the problem but I have no idea how to fix it while still having a larger/taller Entry field

Comment: I found something that has maybe something to do with what you need: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828923/remove-space-between-buttons-in-tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828923/remove-space-between-buttons-in-tkinter) Cheers